# Atlas layout - blank 2nd page in QGIS 3.2 / 2.18

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I've got an atlas in QGIS 3.2 and also 2.18. There is a main frame showing a map with points. Underneath there is a table with further information about the points.

If there are many points, the table extends to a 2nd page. From this point on, there is always a 2nd blank page. I tried to set `Don't export page if frame is empty` with no result. Maybe this option is being overridden at some point (it is automatically unselected after turning the atlas off/on or exporting).

Tried many more things. Now I'm stuck.

Comment: From a cartographical (and also lazy) point of view I would ask first: Is the table really necessary? Could you transfer the bare minimum of information via symbology (color, form, size, pattern)? If not, would small labels suffice? Any map you want to procude should be easily readable and understandable - using a table is the probably most effective way to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, the table is a must. The points are locations that are necessary in emergency procedures. The table contents an ID and a description. Approx. 300 characters long.

Comment: Mapsize and -scale a fixed (as in "part of the standardised layout")?

Comment: Erik, you are my hero. I had to lock the elements in the upper window. I have always used or tried expressions to achieve this :-D

Comment: That's actually not what I meant, but you're welcome =) feel free to write an answer to your post and accept it, since you came along with the solution.

Comment: How did you get the table to extend onto a second page when it's too large for the first page? I've always wanted to be able to do that in an atlas, but never could figure out how.

Comment: There is an option in the item properties. At least in 2.18 and later. Select the table -> item properties -> Frame (without checkbox) -> size mode. In the drop down you can choose expand on next page. I don't have the english version - terms could vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is to lock the items in the layout that are static in size and position. Fixing the position and size by expressions for each element seems to be not enough for the atlas function. [image: Example table extends on 2nd page which will be removed when the table is short enough to fit page 1. All static items have to be locked]